Why aren't my files uploading properly?
I've written a 'File Upload' button for my spfx app, and it appears to work, but the file isn't being uploaded properly.
The user sees a form which allows them to select a file (from their PC), and specify a title. When they click the 'Upload' button, the file should be sent to a specific SharePoint folder.  Once the upload is complete, I set the file's title.
This all appears to work (i.e. I'm not seeing any error in the console), and when I look in the corresponding SharePoint folder I can see the file with the correct title, but the file is only 15bytes in size, and when I try to click on it to open it, I get an "Unable to open file" error.  I've tried PDF and docx files, and the same thing happens for both.
I'm very unfamiliar with SharePoint, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Here's my code:
const Custom_Upload = ({
  folderPath,
  folderFiles,
  tags,
}) => {
  const [formState, setFormState] = React.useState({
    file: undefined,
    title: undefined,
  });

  const sp= spfi().using(SPFx(context));

  const onToggleFile = (f) => {
    setFormState({
      ...formState,
      file: f,
    });
  };

  const onChangeTitle = (t) => {
    setFormState({
      ...formState,
      title: t.currentTarget.value,
    });
  };

  const handleUpload = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let result;
    try {
      if (formState.file.target.size <= 10485760) {
        // small upload
        result = await sp.web
          .getFolderByServerRelativePath(folderPath)
          .files.addUsingPath('filename.docx', formState.file);
      } else {
        // large upload
        result = await sp.web
          .getFolderByServerRelativePath(folderPath)
          .files.addChunked(
            'filename.docx',
            formState.file,
            (data) => {
              console.log(data);
            },
            true
          );
      }
      const item = await result.file.getItem();
      await item.update({
        Title: formState.title
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Error adding file: ", err);
    }
  };

    return (
      <div>
        <form className={styles.formWrapper}>
          <div>
            <label className={styles.label} htmlFor="file">
              Select a file
            </label>
            <input
              name="file"
              id="file"
              className={styles.uploadFormFile}
              type="file"
              onChange={onToggleFile}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label className={styles.label} htmlFor="title">
              File Title
            </label>
            <input
              name="title"
              id="title"
              type="text"
              title="Title"
              onChange={onChangeTitle}
            />
          </div>
          <button
            onClick={handleUpload}
          >
            Upload
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default Custom_Upload;

